# a button pointing to different controller within beginform in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a comparison page which basically doing a comparison between products. the comparison page is wrapped up with beginform and within the form there are at least the **comparison** button and the **select** buttons which will appear for each listed products.

as the name implies, the **comparison** button will load up another page to compare the selected products.  and the **select** button will add the selected product to the cart.

any ideas how to seperate the action between **comparison** button and **select** button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done in two ways I think.

Use [Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx) for your compare button to call another method/controller. Like this, only your form will not get posted, so you need to pass stuff into arguments:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SomeController","Select"))
{
 <button name="selectBtn" value="select">Select</button>
 @Html.ActionLink("Click to Compare", "SomeOtherController", "Compare"
  new { id1=xx, id2=yy },//pass parameters accordingly
  null
  )
}
```

I used [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) of the ActionLink method.

OR

If you really require a button here, you could have two buttons and detect which button was called on the controller and redirect.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("CommonController","Select"))
{
 <button name="button" value="select">Select</button>
 <button name="button" value="compare">Compare</button>
}
```

You controller:

```
public class  CommonController : Controller
{
 public ActionResult Select(string button)//same as the name property of <button>
 {
   if(button == "compare")
   {//do something if you need to 
      //you could again pass in data as part of the route here..
     return RedirectToAction("SomeController", "Compare");
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of HTML, where you cannot post to different url within a single form element. You would require to use javascript to achieve this. On the click of your button you need to call a javascript method and set the forms action url to point to either comparison or select url. Something like this

```
function OnButton1()
{
    document.Form1.action = @url.Action(new {Controller = ctrl1, Action = action });

    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page

    return true;
}

function OnButton2()
{
    document.Form1.action = @url.Action(new {Controller = ctrl2, Action = action });

    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page

    return true;
}
```

Comment: but it will not submit the form collection.

Comment: Assuming that the form is named Form1 and it has some type of checkboxes, it would submit those values